# free c++ compiler for mac not using xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

Are there any free c++ compilers for macs that do not need xcode?

Comment: Why XCode is free. Note XCode is not a compiler it is an IDE. underneath XCode uses g++ (but you can use g++ without XCode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the Developer Tools (which include Xcode), you get GCC installed as well. You can use it from the command line.

```
gcc -o myprogram main.cpp
```

Comment: How do I install the Developer Tools?

Comment: The developer tools are on one of the DVDs that come with OS X.

Comment: Is there any way to get them if I don't have the DVD anymore?

Comment: I suppose this is a correct answer, although it misses the point of not needing xcode, which is to avoid the proprietary license.

Comment: @Ricky: it doesn't require Xcode. It's just GCC. It's conveniently installed with Xcode.

Comment: @Ricky Demer: Is this way you are trying to bootstrap gcc? gcc is shipped under the GPL. Apple can not modify this license (even though it is shipped with XCode) and thus is perfectly usable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have very small needs, you might be able to use a an online IDE like compilr (http://www.compilr.com) or codepad (http://www.codepad.org).

Answer (score 0):

download the latest iPhone SDK from  developer.apple.com

it includes the XCode and GCC tool chain for both Mac and iPhone development.

you won't need any iPhone developer license if you are developing for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Just install xcode, then inside xcode install command line tools. You wont need xcode from that  point on (although i really recommend it).

I hope i helped :)