# free c++ compiler for mac with open source license

Tags: c++, macos, open-source

Are there any free c++ compilers for macs whose license is open source?
(basically one of these http://www.opensource.org/licenses/category)

I don't have the DVD that came with my current OS, and it won't run the version of xcode I already have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [free c++ compiler for mac not using xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446281/free-c-compiler-for-mac-not-using-xcode)

Comment: What version of Mac OS X do you have?

Comment: You can register as Apple developer (free) and [download](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html) Xcode from the web -- it is not open source but solves the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang+LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) are both open source C++ compilers.

Answer (score 1):

just the gcc compiler suite, it includes g++ which is an open source compiler.