# how to build g++

Tags: g++

I'm currently trying to get g++ working, and looking at http://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html, I can't seem to find where it says *how* "to perform a 3-stage bootstrap of the compiler".  Where would I find this information?

(I'm on a mac, in case that matters.)

Comment: Are you sure you want to build gcc from scratch? The gcc provided by apple works rather well.

Comment: To be frank, the fact that you have to ask this question probably means you do not have anywhere near the technical skills needed to do it. And I don't see why you want to do it anyway. As others have suggested, use the port of GCC (which is open source software) that Apple provides.

Comment: I don't have the DVD that came with the OS, and the xcode I do have is to old to run.  Would I be able to get Apple's port of GCC on an open-source license?  If so, do you know how?

Comment: For the Nth time - GCC is open source (to be specific GPL) software - Apple cannot and have not changed this fact.

Comment: If Apple's version is similar enough to also be under the license (and not just to get called the same name), I would expect it to have the same difficulty installing as I mention in the opening post.  Would I be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bootstrap GCC without an already-functioning compiler on your platform:

[From the prerequisites page](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html):

> ISO C90 compiler
>       Necessary to bootstrap GCC, although versions of GCC prior to 3.4 also allow bootstrapping with a traditional (K&R) C compiler.

And to preempt your next question, you also need a functioning compiler (usually GCC) in order to build Clang+LLVM.

It *might* be possible to do what you're [trying so hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446422/free-c-compiler-for-mac-with-open-source-license) [to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446281/free-c-compiler-for-mac-not-using-xcode), by cross-compiling GCC from some other platform ([see this section of the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html#TOC1)). But I imagine this is *not* for the feint of heart, and you'd be far, **far** better off simply updating your copy of Mac OS X to the latest version with Xcode support.

Comment: Well, do you know if there are any free open-source licensed c++ compilers for mac where I wouldn't already need another compiler?  It wouldn't necessarily have to be GCC.  _ _ _ _  P.S.  How do you have the text shown be different from the website the link directs to?

Answer (score 2):

After running `configure`, you do `make bootstrap`

Comment: ip##-#-##-##:~ rickyd$ make bootstrap
-bash: make: command not found

Comment: @Ricky Demer you need to install "make" program

Comment: I see "Make-lang.in", "Makefile.am", and "Makefile.in", none of which have a default application specified to open.  Are you talking about one of these?

Answer (score 0):

From that link:

> For a native build, the default configuration is to perform a 3-stage bootstrap of the compiler when `make' is invoked.

It seems to me that if your configuration isn't tweaked, it should do it out of the box.  Just type `make`.

More specifically, you have to download the source code, and follow the instructions in that whole tutorial in order to build.

A side note - I am finding it hard to believe that there is no easy way to get GCC on an OSX box without having the installation media.  That sounds really annoying :)

**Edit:**

If you are simply trying to write C++ on OSX, you could install one of many other IDEs.  If you are lucky, they may come with their own compiler.  Here is a list of alternatives to XCode:

http://alternativeto.net/desktop/xcode/?profile=mac&platform=mac

Comment: Well, for the next stage listed, the site says to install it with "cd objdir; make install", but terminal says it recognizes neither objdir nor make.  Do you know what that means?